# perforce diff command: how to combine filtering arguments?

Tags: diff, perforce

Documentation says "To pass more than one option to the diff routine, group them together. For example: p4 diff -dub file"
While this might be working for "-d" option, it doesn't work for "-s".

```
> p4 diff -sa ...
file1
> p4 diff -se ...
file2
> p4 diff -sd ...
file3
> p4 diff -saed ...
file1
```

It seems to be taking only the first argument. Is it a bug in perforce or there is a way combine them?

Answer (score 1):

Those options can't be combined.  Trying to specify more than one should be reported as a usage error IMO.

For the most part they specify conditions that are mutually exclusive, so if you were able to combine all those filters ("display only files that are unopened AND opened AND ..."), you'd just get empty output.  :)

Comment: it could be just OR. Don't see a reason not to give this functionality.
I actually looking for a command that would give me the list of all files that are not in sync with depot. If 'p4 diff -saed' worked it would be perfect. Maybe you know any alternative?

Comment: Sounds like `p4 status` and/or `p4 sync -n`?

Comment: p4 sync doesn't check the changes in files. It just checks files' statuses as far as perforce itself concerned. For example, if you delete a file from the file system and then do sync on it nothing will happen since for p4 it's still up to date

Comment: Yes.  `sync -n` tells you what has changed in the depot and not been synced locally, whereas `status` tells you what has changed locally and not been submitted to the depot.